# Как в Perl убрать часть строки

Tags: строки, perl

Есть строка следующего вида:

```
<url>http://plitka-sdvk.ru/Plitka/Ceracasa/Mitica/mitica-terra-316x316-1522/?utm_source=YM&amp;utm_medium=cpc&amp;utm_content=keramicheskaya-plitka&amp;utm_term=1522</url>
```

Как из нее убрать get-часть, чтобы стало

```
<url>http://plitka-sdvk.ru/Plitka/Ceracasa/Mitica/mitica-terra-316x316-1522</url>
```

с помощью perl-функций?

У самого не получилось в связи с незнанием языка.

Comment: регулярным выражением например. как думаете, признака `/?` достаточно, что бы понять, что это начало параметров достаточно ? т.е. скажем удалять все от `/?` до `</url>` ?

Comment: как нибудь так https://regex101.com/r/iIHx7f/1

Comment: Да, работает верно, но как использовать эту регулярку в perl'е?

Comment: @TimurMusharapov может почитать что-то о синтаксисе Perl?

Comment: Ну, в данном случае он ее получит, а не вырежет. Мне просто нужно указать на функцию)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для замены текста в перл используется оператор замены по регулярному выражению `s`. В виде `переменная =~ s/что-меняем/на-что-меняем/[модификаторы]`.

```
my $a='<url>http://plitka-sdvk.ru/Plitka/Ceracasa/Mitica/mitica-terra-316x316-1522/?utm_source=YM&amp;utm_medium=cpc&amp;utm_content=keramicheskaya-plitka&amp;utm_term=1522</url>'

$a =~ s/\/\?.*?(?=<\/url>)//;
```